# Merge dataframe with start and end date of person in a company with dataframe of reporting date for company

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have two dataframes that share the companyid as a common variable:

```
df1 #monthly company reporting data

 rdate  companyid
0 2000-06-30     3.0
1 2000-06-30     4.0
2 2000-06-30     5.0
3 2000-06-30     6.0
4 2000-06-30     7.0

df2 #company data with daily start and end dates for directors

    companyid datestartrole dateendrole  directorid
4         3.0    1995-02-01  2003-01-09    340769.0
5         3.0    2003-01-09  2004-02-24    340769.0
6         3.0    2004-02-24  2007-09-07    340769.0
39        6.0    1976-04-01  1986-01-01     86917.0
40        6.0    1986-01-01  2016-06-30     86917.0
```

I would like to merge these 2 dataframes to have a dataframe of monthly reporting data including the director (directorid) that was active at the reporting date.

So far I have tried the following:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on="companyid", how = "left") #merge based on companyid
df1 = df1[df1["datestartrole"] < df1["rdate"]] #exclude non-active directors
df1 = df1[(df1["dateendrole"] > df1["rdate"]) | (df1["dateendrole"].isna())] #exclude non-active directors
```

This worked relatively well on a smaller dataset. However, since I am working with df1 (7'000'000 x 58) and df2 (170'000 x 7) data points I am not able to compute the first line of code.

Is there a more efficient way to merge these two dataframes to achieve my objective?

Comment: `not able to compute the first line of code` or it takes too long? are there duplicates in the data?

Comment: @sammywemmy the first line of code actually computed with a bit more time but then I got a Memory Error when filtering the data. There can be duplicate company observations at a given time because it is monthly fund data. Meaning that two funds can hold the same stock at a given time.

Comment: I'd suggest dumping your data into sql and run ... or use R's data.table ... efficient... if you are sticking to python land, then `pydatatable` should do the job memory wise and performance wise

Comment: Use Dask version of pandas, they simulate distributed computing and help you with the Memory Error. Checkout their homepage it only needs you to import pandas from their package and all pandas functions should work.